# Getting user-mode dump files on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, minidumps

Windows vista and later has a simple way to configure windows error reporting to save user-mode crash dumps that can be retrieved and read easily [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx) with [these configurable options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680519(v=VS.85).aspx)

Is there a similar solution in windows-xp? I know drwtsn32 is an option, I am looking more for alternatives. Hopefully one that still uses windows error reporting or crash handling.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon some good howto's for creating user dump files on windows xp [here](http://kb.acronis.com/content/15505) and its related pages. Basically you can hang onto a process until it crashes and then analyze the dump file.